# Mock Data from Redis unit testing python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have a class

```
class ReferenceData(celery.Task):
    def __init__(self):
        redis_pool = redis.ConnectionPool()
        self.redis = redis.StrictRedis(connection_pool=redis_pool)

    def get_agents(self,id):
        if condition:
            return self.agents.get(id)
        return self.agents.get(external_id
```

and there is celery task which calls up the following method

```
def save_raisr_event(self, event):
    # Get attributes:
    transcriptions = []
    if trans is not None:
       transcriptions.append(trans)
        self.redis.append(f"{crn}-transcription", ' ' + transcription)
        return 'transcription saved'
```

In the unit testing how to mock the redis connection and mock data from redis in this case the value pf transcription saved in redis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say this is the source code:

**src.py**

```
import celery
import redis


class ReferenceData(celery.Task):
    def __init__(self):
        redis_pool = redis.ConnectionPool()
        self.redis = redis.StrictRedis(connection_pool=redis_pool)

    def save_raisr_event(self, event):
        self.redis.append("crn", 'transcription')
        return self.redis.keys()
```

If you just want to patch the response of the methods within `redis` with static values:

**test_src.py**

```
from src import ReferenceData


def test_redis(mocker):  # Requires <pip install pytest-mock>
    mock_redis_pkg = mocker.patch("src.redis")
    mock_redis = mock_redis_pkg.StrictRedis.return_value

    mocked_keys = ["some", "transactions", "here"]
    mock_redis.keys.return_value = mocked_keys
    assert ReferenceData().save_raisr_event(None) == mocked_keys
```

If you want to store the actual transactions appended, then setup a `dict` that will be updated:

**test_src.py**

```
from src import ReferenceData


def test_redis(mocker):  # Requires <pip install pytest-mock>
    mock_redis_pkg = mocker.patch("src.redis")
    mock_redis = mock_redis_pkg.StrictRedis.return_value

    storage = {}
    mock_redis.append.side_effect = lambda key, value: storage.update({key: value})
    mock_redis.keys.side_effect = lambda: storage.keys()
    assert ReferenceData().save_raisr_event(None) == storage.keys()
    assert storage == {'crn': 'transcription'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This works

Comment: Glad it helped. If it's all the answer you need, you might want to accept it as the answer :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers